# Удаление элементов вектора

Tags: c++, vector

Подскажите, как корректно пройтись по вектору и удалить некоторые его элементы.
Т.е., корректно ли выполнять такие действия?

```
for (auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); it++)
{
    if (check(*it) == false)
        arr.erase(it);
}
```

Или возникнут проблемы с итератором после удаления первого элемента?

---

Прочитал комментарии, всем спасибо за помощь

Пересмотрел код и понял, что не совсем полно поставил задачу:

```
for (auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); it++)
{
    if (check(*it) == false)
    {
        // сделать-что-то полезное с данными, которые потом будут удалены

        arr.erase(it);
    }
}
```

Если воспользоваться советом @Harry, то тогда код можно же преобразовать к такому:

```
arr.erase(remove_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](auto x) {
    if (check(x))
    {
        // сделать что-то полезное с данными из x

        return true;
    }

    return false; 
}), arr.end());
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему не [так](https://ideone.com/B79y8T):

```
arr.erase(remove_if(arr.begin(),arr.end(),
                    [](auto x){ return !check(x); }),
          arr.end());
```

? Как по мне - понятнее и никаких проблем с итераторами... Вероятно, еще и быстрее, чем убирать по одному элементу...

Если перепишете `check` так, чтоб работал наоборот - то и лямбда-выражение (или `bind`) не потребуется.

Если уж позарез нужен цикл - то воспользуйтесь тем, что `erase` возвращает итератор на элемент, следующий за удаленным:

```
for(auto i = arr.begin(); i != arr.end();
    i = (check(*i) == false) ? arr.erase(i) : i+1);
```

Но учтите, что тут сложность - квадратичная, в отличие от `remove_if` (спасибо @pavel).

Comment: способы действительно хорошие, просто тогда мне придется сделать двойной проход по массиву, сначала для удаления неугодных элементов, а потом для работы с угодными элементами (у меня в реализации), но это совершенно несмертельно, так что наверное так и реализую, как ты советуешь

Comment: "Если перепишете check так, чтоб работал наоборот - то и лямбда-выражение (или bind) не потребуется." - вот это не очень понял, что имеется в виду?

Comment: Вы проверяете и удаляете при `check(*it) == false`. Если будете удалять при `newcheck(*it) == true`, то лямбда-0выражение не потребуется, просто передадите третьим параметром `newcheck`.

Comment: вот цикл как раз в таком виде я бы писать не советовал. Квадратичная сложность на ровном месте.

Comment: @pavel А он для вектора в любом виде при удалении по одному элементу будет квадратичный :) Впрочем, `remove_if` - тоже, из-за перемещения неудаленных.

Comment: @Harry не совсем. можно в 1 проход легко. Через лямбду в 1 проход и будет кстати.

Comment: @pavel Да, подумал - можно. Логично. `remove_if` даст линейность.

Answer (score 2):

`erase` вернёт следующий итератор, элемент будет удалён, но будет проблема с инкрементом, так что нужно добавить вспомогательный код.

```
for (auto it = arr.begin(); it != arr.end(); it++)
{
    if (check(*it) == false){
       it = arr.erase(it);
       --it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Итератор после удаления станет не валидным и it++ сделать будет нельзя. К тому же, на каждую итерацию будет перестроение вектора, что в общем случаем считается тяжелой операцией.
Можно перенести все правильные значения в новый вектор:

```
decltype(arr) new_vector;
new_vector.reserve(arr.size());
for (auto i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
{
    new_vector.emplace_back(std::move(arrr[i]));
}
arr.swap(new_vector)
```

Answer (score 1):

Альтернатива ответу @Komodosh.

Чтобы не декрементировать итератор лишний раз, можно сделать так:

```
auto it = arr.begin();
while (it != arr.end())
{
    if (check(*it) == false)
        it = arr.erase(it);
    else
        it++;
}
```

Но лучше послушать Harry и взять erase-remove idiom.